# Performance Issue while changing DB Schema at Runtime in .Net Core and EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

I am working on Multi Tenant application where each user has different database schema.

Based on user credentials we will get which schema he belongs.

Below is my Context Class which dynamically refreshes context every time based on schemaName

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

public string SchemaName { get; set; }


public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
{

}

public ApplicationDbContext(string schemaname)
    : base()
{
    SchemaName = schemaname;
}

public DbSet<EmployeeDetail> EmployeeDetail { get; set; }



protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{

    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
    var configuration = builder.Build();

    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection().AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
                        .AddSingleton<IModelCustomizer, SchemaContextCustomize>()
                        .BuildServiceProvider();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration["ConnectionStrings:SchemaDBConnection"]).UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   // modelBuilder.MapProduct(SchemaName);

    modelBuilder.RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SchemaName))
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(SchemaName);
    }
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}

public string CacheKey
{
    get { return SchemaName; }
}

public class SchemaContextCustomize : ModelCustomizer
{
    public SchemaContextCustomize(ModelCustomizerDependencies dependencies)
        : base(dependencies)
    {

    }
    public override void Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext dbContext)
    {
        base.Customize(modelBuilder, dbContext);

        string schemaName = (dbContext as ApplicationDbContext).SchemaName;
        (dbContext as ApplicationDbContext).SchemaName = schemaName;

    }
}
```

Above code works perfectly without any issues. `OnConfiguring` method is responsible for providing correct schema everytime

Major concern is related to performance For every request below line is taking almost 40% of Time every time for initializing context

```
base.Customize(modelBuilder, dbContext);
```

Is there any way to increase performance, ideally this should be called once.

What is the proper way for changing schema at runtime based on user so that OnConfiguring method is called only once?